# Remove :8080 from the URL of WAMP Server

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

My WAMP Server is working on port 8080 and whenever I want to open the page I have to put :8080 in the url. Is there anyone to ignore :8080 from the URL

on the httpd.conf file

```
Listen 8080

ServerName localhost:8080
```

on the wampmanager.tpl file

```
...
[Menu.Left]
;WAMPMENULEFTSTART
...
Type: item; Caption: "${w_localhost}"; Action: run; FileName: "${c_navigator}"; Parameters: "http://localhost:8080/"; Glyph: 5
Type: item; Caption: "${w_phpmyadmin}"; Action: run; FileName: "${c_navigator}"; Parameters: "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/"; Glyph: 5
...
Type: item; Caption: "${c_webgrind}"; Action: run; FileName: "${c_navigator}"; Parameters: "http://localhost:8080/webgrind/"; Glyph: 5
...
```

Still now I have to put :8080 in my URL

Comment: Be warned: this often has conflicts if other programs are using port 80. i.e. Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the WAMP server icon and from the menu under Config Files select httpd.conf. A long text file will open up in notepad. In this file scroll down to the line that reads Port 8080 and change this to read Port 80, Save the file and close notepad. Once again click on the wamp server icon and select restart all services.

Also on a newer version of WAMP, click the WAMP server icon > Apache > httpd.conf, then change the line Listen 8080 to Listen 80 or any port you want.

EDIT: IF this doesn't work (which is a definite possibility) Then your best bet is to either bookmark "Localhost:8080" or make a desktop shortcut for ease of access, or to simply figure out why you can't run it on port 80 - and fix that.

Comment: I want to run my WAMP server on port 8080. but do not want to add :8080 in URL

Comment: Well you cannot do that, browsers expect web servers to be on port 80, if you change the listen to 8080 then you have to add `:8080` on every url. Best oto work out why you cannot run on 80 and fix that.

Comment: Oh, there is a way to do this; let me look it up. Essentially what you want to do is set it to run on :8080 and have your browser load that whenever you type localhost.

Comment: @Tainted The hosts file does not allow a port number extension `127.0.0.1:xxxx loclahost` so this will not work.

Comment: I can not put the port number in hosts file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I wasn't sure so I posted alternative answers - after looking into this it's not possible in normal windows / linux distros. He needs to follow the other answers I gave in  my post.

Answer (score -1):

Change all instances of 8080 in the config settings to 80, and restart apache.

Comment: I want to run my WAMP server on port 8080. but do not want to add :8080 in URL

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **IIS** try out the following:

To uninstall IIS using Add or Remove a Windows Component in Control Panel

1. From the Start menu, click Control Panel.
2. Double-click Add or Remove Programs.
3. Click Add/Remove Windows Components.
4. In the Components list click the Application Server check box.
5. Click Next.
6. Click Close when uninstallation of IIS is complete.
7. Restart your PC

After restarting, type `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/index.php`

Hope this helps! If this doesn't work, check the application or service using port 80.

```
Apache > Service > Test Port 80
```

After checking the port, disable or close that application. You may probably have Skype using Port 80, sign out from Skype.

Comment: Well, he obviously is using Apache (WAMP) not ISS.

Comment: Ok. If he's using WAMP and IIS at the same time, IIS should be uninstalled.